# How to get from outside value inside subscriber

Tags: angular

I'm developing dashboard with chartjs and Angular 7 and I need to display some information from an object inside tooltip.

[image]

I'm able to get the object in console log, but I'don't know how to get the value from a subscriber inside function that permits me to display custom tooltip on screen.

this is my code.

```
ngOnInit() {

this.batches.forEach(batch => {
        let batchID = batch.batch_id;
        this.dashboardService.getBatchId(batchID).subscribe(singleBatch => {
          this.batch = singleBatch;
          console.log(this.batch)
          let batchName = this.batch.name //<-- THIS IS MY VARIABLE
          console.log(batchName)
        })
      })
}

Duration = {
    tooltips: {
      // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
      enabled: false,

      custom: function(tooltipModel) {
          // Tooltip Element
          var tooltipEl = document.getElementById('chartjs-tooltip');

          // Create element on first render
          if (!tooltipEl) {
              tooltipEl = document.createElement('div');
              tooltipEl.id = 'chartjs-tooltip';
              tooltipEl.innerHTML = '<table style="background-color: #eee;"></table>';
              document.body.appendChild(tooltipEl);
          }

          function getBody(bodyItem) {
              return bodyItem.lines;
          }

          // Set Text
          if (tooltipModel.body) {
              var titleLines = tooltipModel.title || [];
              var bodyLines = tooltipModel.body.map(getBody);
              innerHtml += '<tbody>';

              bodyLines.forEach(function(body, i) {
                  var span = '<span>' +
                  '<p>Batch: </p>' + //<----HERE IT IS THE PLACE WHERE I WANT TO PUT BATCHNAME
                  '</span>';
                  innerHtml += '<tr><td>' + span + body + '</td></tr>';
              });
              innerHtml += '</tbody>';
          }
      }

  }
};
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: did that answer your question?

Comment: Excuse me for the later answer, yes your hint is helpful, but It's not so clear for me, you can provide me an example based on my case? thanks a lot

Comment: Your example wont work, you have a list of batches, and you're trying to put a single batch name on their, which batch are you trying to put there

Comment: Theres no reason to be accessing the dom directly put your html in the template and just pass the batch into the controller,  I showed you how to do it in my example, you might want to watch an angular tutorial video

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'm using chart.js so the only one thing that i have in html is a canvas, nothing more. So I need to manipulate everything from typescript side. My goals is to retrive the batch.name (and i can access to it by foreach loop) and then take my bactch.name and put it inside the custom tooltip function, so it can be displayed

Comment: Sago just make your duration object an array, and wrap it in a for each, for the batches like you did above

Comment: Why I'had downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to Pseudo-code this because i'm not on my development machine.

From your code you already have a variable for your batches e.g this.batches, So why are you going back to your service to obtain your batches? e.g

```
 this.batches.forEach(batch => { console.log(batch.name) });
```

You just need a function in to display the tooltip e.g

```
 tooltip(batch: Batch) => { batch.name }
```

Then you should just call it from your html

```
<div *ngFor="let batch in batches">
    <div class="tooltip">{{tooltip(batch)}}</div>
</div>
```